# ABP ReactJS Template accessing current login data

Tags: reactjs, aspnetboilerplate

May someone help me to get the name, surname etc of the current user?

I've tried this so far:

```
export interface IHeaderProps {
  sessionStore?: SessionStore;
}
...
 async componentDidMount() {
    await this.props.sessionStore?.getCurrentLoginInformations();
  }
...
  render() {

    const user = this.props.sessionStore?.currentLogin.user.name;

    return (

      <Avatar name={user}   />

    }
...
```

but it throws

> sessionStore is undefined

Thanks so much.